# I can't upgrade Facebook SDK to 9.0.0 for iOS from Swift Package Dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk, swift-package-manager

I've received an email from Facebook pointing that I have to upgrade **Facebook SDK** of my iOS app to the latest version. It means I should go from `7.1.1` to `9.0.0`.

The case is I have FB installed via Swift Package Dependencies:

[image]

But when I go to `File` > `Swift Packages` > `Update to Latest Package Versions` no updates are installed at all.

Does anyone know what could I do to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share how are the version rules for this package? Maybe it's being limited there?

Comment: Hard to believe but true... As simply as checking these versions rules! Changed and solved, hahaha. Thanks!!